# using QPainter to draw a hangman

Tags: python, pyqt5, drawing, qpainter

I am using python and am new to PyQt (and a bit new to python as well). I want to create a basic hangman game, and I have all of the controls figured out except I don't know how to draw the head, body, etc when a wrong letter is pressed. I tried using QPainter somehow but it doesn't work and upon research, some people say I have to use QPix map which I haven't heard of before so I am a bit confused. Here is the main bit of my code (I skipped me configuring the buttons for letters):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import re

allowed = re.compile('[a-zA-Z ]')


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    answer = [] #list of correct charcters they have inputted
    required = '' #string containing the solution
    indicies = {} #indicies mapping the index of each correct character in solution to the actual character
    wrong_count = 0

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ### sets up all the buttons for letters of the alphabet, lines, etc. I have this figured out.
        self.newgame = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.newgame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 290, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.newgame.setFont(font)
        self.newgame.setObjectName("newgame")
        self.newgame.setText('New game')
        self.newgame.clicked.connect(self.restart)
        self.newgame.hide()

        self.start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 380, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.start.setFont(font)
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.start.setText("Begin")
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.get_name)

        self.answerbox = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.answerbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 480, 601, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.answerbox.setFont(font)
        self.answerbox.setText("")
        self.answerbox.setObjectName("answerbox")

        self.win = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.win.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 400, 601, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.win.setFont(font)
        self.win.setText("")
        self.win.setObjectName("win")

        self.wrongtext = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.wrongtext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 500, 601, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.wrongtext.setFont(font)
        self.wrongtext.setText("Sorry, please type a valid string, without any special characters")
        self.wrongtext.adjustSize()
        self.wrongtext.setObjectName("wrongtext")
        self.wrongtext.hide()

        self.lost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 500, 601, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lost.setFont(font)
        self.lost.setText("Sorry, you lost")
        self.lost.adjustSize()
        self.lost.setObjectName("lost")
        self.lost.hide()

    def get_name(self):
        text = App().text ##prompts user input for word
        if text == '':
            return
        elif allowed.match(text):
            Ui_MainWindow.required = text
            self.answerbox.setText('_ '*len(text))
            self.wrongtext.hide()
            self.check_space(text)
            self.answerbox.adjustSize()
            self.start.hide()
        else:
            self.wrongtext.show()


    def check_space(self, text):
        list1 = list(text)
        for ch in list1:
            if ch == ' ':
                self.revealer(ch)
                Ui_MainWindow.answer.append(ch)

    def clicked(self, ans): ### connected to letter buttons
        if ans.lower() in Ui_MainWindow.required:
            for _ in range(Ui_MainWindow.required.count(ans.lower())):
                Ui_MainWindow.answer.append(ans.lower())
            self.revealer(ans.lower())
            self.checker()
        else:
            Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count += 1
            self.paintEvent()

    def paintEvent(self): ##### this is what doesn't work but I want it to be something like this
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count == 1: ### face
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 10, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(250, 320, 20, 20)
            return
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count == 2: ### body
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.drawLine(250, 340, 250, 360)
            return
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count == 3: ###legs
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.drawLine(250, 360, 260, 370)
            return
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count == 4:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.drawLine(250, 360, 240, 370)
            return
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count == 5: ####arms
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.drawLine(250, 350, 260, 340)
            return
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count == 6:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.drawLine(250, 350, 240, 340)
            self.lost.show()
            self.newgame.show()


    def revealer(self, ans):
        index = Ui_MainWindow.required.index(ans) #find the index of a character from answer list in required list
        Ui_MainWindow.indicies[index*2] = ans #assigns index to the character, to be used for displayed
        try:
            while True: ##checks if clicked character appears multiple times in the answer string and appends all of them
                index = Ui_MainWindow.required.index(ans, index+1)
                Ui_MainWindow.indicies[index*2] = ans
        except:
            pass
        displayed = '_ '*len(Ui_MainWindow.required)
        temp_list = list(displayed)
        for index, ch in Ui_MainWindow.indicies.items():
            temp_list[index] = ch
        str2 = ''
        displayed = str2.join(temp_list)
        self.answerbox.setText(displayed)

    def checker(self):
        if sorted(Ui_MainWindow.answer) == sorted(list(Ui_MainWindow.required)):
            self.win.setText("You won!")
            self.newgame.show()
    def restart(self):
        Ui_MainWindow.answer = []
        Ui_MainWindow.required = ''
        Ui_MainWindow.indicies = {}
        Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count = 1
        self.win.setText("")
        self.answerbox.setText("")
        self.newgame.hide()
        self.lost.hide()
        self.start.show()

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 input dialogs - pythonspot.com'
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(380, 280, 640, 480)
        self.get_name()

    def get_name(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Text Input Dialog', 'Enter your word:')
        self.text = text
        if text and ok:
            return str(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry it's quite long. Basically when I run it everything works the way I want it, except if I press the wrong letter, nothing happens. It doesn't throw an error or anything. I tried using just QPainter separately to see how it works, and I made it draw a circle, line, etc, but not one by one the way I want. Thanks for reading and I'd appreciate any answers. Sorry if my layout for my question was bad, I only started using this website yesterday, so am not familiar with how things work just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paintEvent` should be part of your `QMainWindow` instance, not of the object you use for setting up the ui. In fact, most of the methods in `Ui_MainWindow` really belong to your `MainWindow` instance, so probably the easiest way to fix this is to just make `Ui_MainWindow` a subclass of `QMainWindow`, i.e.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # You could consider making these instance variables instead of class variables
    answer = [] #list of correct charcters they have inputted
    required = '' #string containing the solution
    indicies = {} #indicies mapping the index of each correct character in solution to the actual character
    wrong_count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.setupUi(self)

    def paintEvent(self, event):    # <-- paintEvent receives the paint event as an input parameter
        ....

    # all other methods as before


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    MainWindow.resize(800,600)
    app.exec()
```

This will at least call the `paintEvent`, but there are still a number of issues with the implementation of `paintEvent`. For one, `painEvent` is called automatically every time the window needs redrawing. You shouldn't try to call this function yourself. If you think your widget needs redrawing you could use `update` instead.

Also, `paintEvent` is meant just for painting a widget and nothing else. This means that everything not-paint related like showing or hiding widgets should be moved elsewhere. In your case, the lines

```
self.lost.show()
self.newgame.show()
```

should be removed from `paintEvent` and moved to for example `clicked` instead, e.g.

```
def clicked(self, ans): ### connected to letter buttons
    if ans.lower() in Ui_MainWindow.required:
        for _ in range(Ui_MainWindow.required.count(ans.lower())):
            Ui_MainWindow.answer.append(ans.lower())
        self.revealer(ans.lower())
        self.checker()
    else:
        Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count += 1
        if self.wrong_count >= 6:
            self.lost.show()
            self.newgame.show()
```

Finally, since you only check for equality of `wrong_count` in `paintEvent`, at most one limb will be drawn at any time. This can be fixed by checking if `wrong_count` is larger than a certain value instead of equal to, e.g.

```
    def paintEvent(self, event): 
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.begin(self)
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count >= 1: ### face
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 10, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(250, 320, 20, 20)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count >= 2: ### body
            painter.drawLine(250, 340, 250, 360)
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count >= 3: ###legs
            painter.drawLine(250, 360, 260, 370)
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count >= 4:
            painter.drawLine(250, 360, 240, 370)
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count >= 5: ####arms
            painter.drawLine(250, 350, 260, 340)
        if Ui_MainWindow.wrong_count >= 6:
            painter.drawLine(250, 350, 240, 340)
        painter.end()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I get what you mean. However, some of the bits of code I left out earlier used 'MainWindow', e.g.: under def setupUi, I had: self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow), and some more. Sorry, it's my fault for not including it in my code before, but as you can see, after using your method, 'mainwindow' becomes undefined and I am not sure how to fix this. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Vijay within `setupUi`, `MainWindow` refers to the input variable of `setupUi`, not to the globally defined variable in your code. I didn't change anything about the signature of `setupUi`, so `MainWindow` is still defined within `setupUi` and using `self.centralwidget=QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)` in `setupUi` should still work fine.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I made it work using your method thanks a lot :) I understand my mistake now.